# Log4j viewer that allows multiple log files to be interwoven together

Tags: log4j

I've been looking around for a log4j viewer that allows for multiple log files to be interwoven together. Right now I've been trying to do it on Chainsaw but it opens every seperate log file into a different window.

My hope is to look at log files for my UI and for the backend simultaneously, but want to have them in the same window, but sorted together by the time. Does anyone know of a tool that can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chainsaw can do it.  Here are two ways:

1. Change your 'tab name/event routing expression' in the preferences panel to something that would cause them to route to the same tab (like 'EVENTS', which is just fixed text and will cause all events to be routed to a tab called 'Unknown').
2. Use a custom expression logpanel expression: view menu, create tab from expression.  Events matching the expression from any tab will be added to the new tab..sort of like a database view.  As new events come in, if they match the new expression, they will also end up in this new tab.

I'm probably using menu names from the latest developer snapshot - it has a ton of new features.  Available here:
http://people.apache.org/~sdeboy

Comment: I'm using the web start Chainsaw which doesn't seem to allow for this.

Comment: It should have these features, but I'd really suggest using the latest version...it has a -lot- of new features...auto-load fileappender configurations from a log4j configuration file, search improved, performance improved...colorized bars on the right you can click on to jump to events...just extract the tarball and run the shell script..should work just as well (or better than) the webstart version.  You can also create shortcuts to that script and pass in a chainsaw configuration xml file as an arg to the script to get it to load a different configuration file.